# Question: next step after regression analysis? how to tell if multiple variables all co-correlate?

Tags: regression, correlation, clustering, pca, factor-analysis

I am new to regression analysis and I have found that my 'independent variable' or predictor correlates with several dependent variables (through multiple linear regression tests) in a way that supports my prior hypothesis. I am trying to figure out the best next step.

Is there a way to figure out if all these variables are all correlated together? By that i mean is there a way to tell if their is subset of samples for which all the variables are high, and and another subset for which all the variables are low? Is this called Principal component analysis, factor analysis or clustering analysis?

can anybody suggest an article or a next step?

thanks!

Comment: By "independent variable", do you mean X or Y (predictor or response)? Likewise for "dependent variable". I can't tell if you are using the terms 'backwards' relative to their most common usage, or if you have a multiple response variable situation.

Comment: i was trying to say that my predictor (X) was correlated with several different response variables in independent linear regression experiments.   To be clear about the situation, my predictor is a gene, and the other response variables are other genes which are known to be related to each other.